# Актуальность COM, ATL, MFC

Tags: atl, mfc, com, c++

Здравствуйте.

Собственно вопрос состоит в том: почему до сих пор используются MFC, COM, ATL и так ли они хороши, чтобы сейчас их использовать? Дело в том, что я заметил, что на многих вакансиях C++ Developera в перечне необходимых навыков и знаний присутствуют MFC и\или COM, ATL. Неужели их так перспективно учить?

Почему? Где они используются и зачем их применять?

Взять тот же MFC. Он очень громоздкий, тяжелый, неудобный и т.д.... Есть ведь, к примеру, Qt, который намного удобнее и работать с ним приятнее. В чем смысл MFC тогда? Стоит ли его изучать? Зачем на нем писать новые проекты, когда есть более удобные фреймворки (Qt, GTK, SDL в конце концов).

А COM... Он тоже достаточно неудобный и сложный (впрочем как и кривой). Не понимаю почему в вакансиях они так часто встречаются. Enterprise? Но ведь для этого сейчас есть .NET (С# и т.д.) ну и Java конечно, да и такие вещи как WPF, где можно интерфейс сделать довольно-таки быстро и выглядеть он будет прилично.

P.S.: Особенно будет интересно послушать ответы Senior C++ Developerов и про то, используют ли они в своей работе данные вещи (это, конечно, зависит от специализации, но всё же), если да, то зачем и где, а также стоит ли эти технологии изучать (я знаю лишь основы этих технологий, мне тот же Qt больше нравится, чем, к примеру, MFC).

Comment: Я думаю, в конторах имеется много старых проектов, которые нужно поддерживать.

Comment: Технология SAPI от microsoft предназначенная для синтезирования текста в речь и обратно использует технологию COM. А сейчас есть много программ "говорилок", принимающих команды от человека, обслуживающие его по имени и.т.д. То есть COM скорее всего еще протянет, хотя и не очень удобный он.

Comment: DirectX, если не ошибаюсь, это сплошь COM-интерфейсы. Это, в принципе, тоже довольно веская причина для продолжения существования это технологии

Comment: На COM вроде как весь NET держится (хотя я и не уверен в данном утверждении)

Answer (score 7):

COM - универсальный клей для Windows. COM компонент можно написать на любом языке и вызвать из любого языка. Большое количество функций в Windows основано на COM.

Даже новое WinRT по своей сути является оберткой над COM-овскими объектами.

COM - это фундаментальная часть винды как и WinAPI.

Возможно, для прикладного софта COM стал громоздким, тяжелым, неудобным так же, как и WinAPI, но он - важная часть современной винды.

Answer (score 2):

Всё дело в том, что есть куча старых проектов, которые используют эти технологии. Учить их вовсе необязательно, если не собираетесь сопровождать какой-нибудь старый проект. Microsoft-овская библиотека вообще не прижилась и сейчас существует множество лучших возможностей. СОМ использется в основном для сопровождения. За ATL не ручаюсь — не в курсе.

Comment: Т.е. если написано такое в требованиях, то это обязательно будет поддержка старых проектов? Я действительно так и предполагал, но проблема в том, что там обычно написано о разработке нового ПО, да и достаточно часто эти требования указывают, поэтому я и не мог быть спокойным, т.к. собственно я не очень много опыта с COM, MFC, ATL имею и технологии мне эти не особо нравятся (как я уже упоминал), но, однако, неужели мне придется их учить, чтобы проходить на вакансию, скажем, Senior C++ Developer (где такие навыки в обязательных находятся).

Comment: Ну, знать эти технологии желательно. Тем более, если Вы их знаете и знаете хорошо, то сможете вышестоящее руководство или заказчика переубедить их использовать, скажем, в пользу того же Qt

Comment: Это знать не обязательно, т.к. помимо написания нового софта во многих конторах есть ещё сопровождение старого, то желательно знание.

Answer (score 0):

Qt, однозначно, сейчас более востребован